# How to use OAuth 2.0 just for authorization client application in my API

Tags: php, rest, oauth, oauth-2.0, authorization

I have API in my site, and need to use access token for every request from client application. I don't have a user for authentification. I have client id in db of my site and client app will have that client id too. What stages I need to do using OAuth 2.0 from phpleague? Do I need to use just 'refresh token grant'?

Answer (score 0):

What i can understand from your question .Yes, Access tokens reside for a fix time,probably for an hour but after that you need to use a refresh token and that will do the work.

Comment: In my case I don't need step like authorization?

Comment: authorization depends on you , if you wanna provide an extra layer  of security that's up to  you but when you authorize client through their google IDs you don't have to do the extra effort.Google does it for you but if you do use the concept of refresh tokens and store them with you.Then you do need to make sure that they are safe and no one gets them.